# ACF Google Map - Change Styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I have Wordpress site up and running, and using ACF plugin, I created Google Map field. That's all great, but I want to change default google map style. I need some lighter – grayscale style for my site map. 
I used code below from ACF documentation, and as I said it works great, but when I try to change any of styles nothing happens.
I must point that I’m not javascript/jquery savvy so please take that in consideration. 
I did go through whole google map API documentation, but I just can’t make any of it. I tried bunch of stuff, and either nothing happens or I trashed google map.
So could someone just point me in right direction, or give me a sample code with explanation where to use it. Should I remove part of existing code or not, or just add additional peace of code etc?
Thanks in advance, and all the best!

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

/*
*  render_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function render_map( $el ) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    // vars
    var args = {
        zoom        : 11,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };



    // create map               
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];

    // add markers
    $markers.each(function(){

        add_marker( $(this), map );

    });

    // center map
    center_map( map );


}

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/
function initialize() {

  // Create an array of styles.
  var styleArray = ('mojaMapa')[
  {
    featureType: "all",
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -80 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road.arterial",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#00ffee" },
      { saturation: 50 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "water",
    elementType: "geometry.fill",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#00ffee" },
      { saturation: 50 },
      { color: '#adc9b8'} 
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "poi.business",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];

map.setOptions({styles: styles});

  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
  // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
  map.setOptions({styles: styles}); 
  // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
  // to the map type control.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6468, 37.581),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: (google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 'mojaMapa')
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
  map.mapTypes.set('mojaMapa', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('mojaMapa');
}

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open( map, marker );

        });
    }

}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

    // vars
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

        bounds.extend( latlng );

    });

    // only 1 marker?
    if( map.markers.length == 1 )
    {
        // set center of map
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        map.setZoom( 16 );
    }
    else
    {
        // fit to bounds
        map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }

}

/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function(){

        render_map( $(this) );

    });

});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are so many style options you can try by this [google map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

I made some changes in styles option, You can try your own colors.

```
var args = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    scrollwheel: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    },
    styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#e9ebed"},{"saturation":-78},{"lightness":67},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffffff"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#bbc0c4"},{"saturation":-93},{"lightness":31},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffffff"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#e9ebed"},{"saturation":-90},{"lightness":-8},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#e9ebed"},{"saturation":10},{"lightness":69},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.locality","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#2c2e33"},{"saturation":7},{"lightness":19},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"hue":"#bbc0c4"},{"saturation":-93},{"lightness":31},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"hue":"#bbc0c4"},{"saturation":-93},{"lightness":-2},{"visibility":"simplified"}]}]
};
```

Please update your latitude and longitude options in center option before using this code.

Comment: I noticed now there are no directions on this ACF google map form. Is there a way to add directions / routes option to this code?

Comment: try to use Google Map Direction service for that. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

Answer (score 2):

here is the complete js code for styling your map :

```
(function($) { /* * render_map * * This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element * * @type function * @date 8/11/2013 * @since 4.3.0 * * @param $el (jQuery element) * @return n/a */ function render_map( $el ) {  // Create an array of styles.  var styles =   [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":33}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2e5d4"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c5dac6"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c5c6c6"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e4d7c6"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#fbfaf7"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#acbcc9"}]}]  // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name: "Styled Map"});  // var  var $markers = $el.find('.marker');  // vars  var args = {  zoom : 16,  center : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),  mapTypeControl  : true,  mapTypeControlOptions: {  mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']  },  zoomControl : true,  zoomControlOptions: {  style : google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,  position : google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER  }  };  // create map   var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.  map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');  // add a markers reference  map.markers = [];  // add markers  $markers.each(function(){  add_marker( $(this), map );  });  // center map  center_map( map ); } /* * add_marker * * This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map * * @type function * @date 8/11/2013 * @since 4.3.0 * * @param $marker (jQuery element) * @param map (Google Map object) * @return n/a */ function add_marker( $marker, map ) {  // var  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );  // create marker  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  position : latlng,  map : map  });  // add to array  map.markers.push( marker );  // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow  if( $marker.html() )  {  // create info window  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({  content : $marker.html()  });  // show info window when marker is clicked  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  infowindow.open( map, marker );  });  } } /* * center_map * * This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map * * @type function * @date 8/11/2013 * @since 4.3.0 * * @param map (Google Map object) * @return n/a */ function center_map( map ) {  // vars  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  // loop through all markers and create bounds  $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );  bounds.extend( latlng );  });  // only 1 marker?  if( map.markers.length == 1 )  {  // set center of map  map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );  map.setZoom( 16 );  }  else  {  // fit to bounds  map.fitBounds( bounds );  } } /* * document ready * * This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded) * * @type function * @date 8/11/2013 * @since 5.0.0 * * @param n/a * @return n/a */ $(document).ready(function(){  $('.acf-map').each(function(){  render_map( $(this) );  }); }); })(jQuery);
```

You can choose differents styles here : https://snazzymaps.com/ 
Change

```
var styles = your code
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://snazzymaps.com/ or google https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com. You had your style code to "styles:".

```
function initMap( $el ) {

// Find marker elements within map.
var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

// Create gerenic map.
var mapArgs = {
    zoom        : $el.data('zoom') || 16,
    mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#e9ebed"},{"saturation":-78},{"lightness":67},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffffff"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#bbc0c4"},{"saturation":-93},{"lightness":31},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffffff"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#e9ebed"},{"saturation":-90},{"lightness":-8},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#e9ebed"},{"saturation":10},{"lightness":69},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.locality","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#2c2e33"},{"saturation":7},{"lightness":19},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"hue":"#bbc0c4"},{"saturation":-93},{"lightness":31},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"hue":"#bbc0c4"},{"saturation":-93},{"lightness":-2},{"visibility":"simplified"}]}]

};
var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], mapArgs );

// Add markers.
map.markers = [];
$markers.each(function(){
    initMarker( $(this), map );
});

// Center map based on markers.
centerMap( map );

// Return map instance.
return map;
}
```